# Trying to get property 'model_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel, controller, voyager

So I get this error when I'm trying to use the voyager themes, I want to use the voyager's theme since the page is on the admin side so I want to make it uniform. 
I realized that I also need to to extend the views so I create this controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Toko;
use App\Models\SubOrder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use TCG\Voyager\Database\Schema\SchemaManager;
use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController;

class OrderController extends VoyagerBaseController
{
    //***************************************
    //               ____
    //              |  _ \
    //              | |_) |
    //              |  _ <
    //              | |_) |
    //              |____/
    //
    //      Browse our Data Type (B)READ
    //
    //****************************************

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // GET THE SLUG, ex. 'posts', 'pages', etc.
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        // GET THE DataType based on the slug
        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('browse', app($dataType->model_name));

        $getter = $dataType->server_side ? 'paginate' : 'get';

        $search = (object) ['value' => $request->get('s'), 'key' => $request->get('key'), 'filter' => $request->get('filter')];

        $searchNames = [];
        if ($dataType->server_side) {
            $searchable = SchemaManager::describeTable(app($dataType->model_name)->getTable())->pluck('name')->toArray();
            $dataRow = Voyager::model('DataRow')->whereDataTypeId($dataType->id)->get();
            foreach ($searchable as $key => $value) {
                $field = $dataRow->where('field', $value)->first();
                $displayName = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $value));
                if ($field !== null) {
                    $displayName = $field->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name');
                }
                $searchNames[$value] = $displayName;
            }
        }

        $orderBy = $request->get('order_by', $dataType->order_column);
        $sortOrder = $request->get('sort_order', $dataType->order_direction);
        $usesSoftDeletes = false;
        $showSoftDeleted = false;

        // Next Get or Paginate the actual content from the MODEL that corresponds to the slug DataType
        if (strlen($dataType->model_name) != 0) {
            $model = app($dataType->model_name);

            if ($dataType->scope && $dataType->scope != '' && method_exists($model, 'scope'.ucfirst($dataType->scope))) {
                $query = $model->{$dataType->scope}();
            } else {
                $query = $model::select('*');
            }

            // Query menampilkan hanya toko pedagang

            if(auth()->user()->hasRole('pedagang')) {

                $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());

            }

            // Use withTrashed() if model uses SoftDeletes and if toggle is selected
            if ($model && in_array(SoftDeletes::class, class_uses_recursive($model)) && Auth::user()->can('delete', app($dataType->model_name))) {
                $usesSoftDeletes = true;

                if ($request->get('showSoftDeleted')) {
                    $showSoftDeleted = true;
                    $query = $query->withTrashed();
                }
            }

            // If a column has a relationship associated with it, we do not want to show that field
            $this->removeRelationshipField($dataType, 'browse');

            if ($search->value != '' && $search->key && $search->filter) {
                $search_filter = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? '=' : 'LIKE';
                $search_value = ($search->filter == 'equals') ? $search->value : '%'.$search->value.'%';
                $query->where($search->key, $search_filter, $search_value);
            }

            if ($orderBy && in_array($orderBy, $dataType->fields())) {
                $querySortOrder = (!empty($sortOrder)) ? $sortOrder : 'desc';
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([
                    $query->orderBy($orderBy, $querySortOrder),
                    $getter,
                ]);
            } elseif ($model->timestamps) {
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->latest($model::CREATED_AT), $getter]);
            } else {
                $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([$query->orderBy($model->getKeyName(), 'DESC'), $getter]);
            }

            // Replace relationships' keys for labels and create READ links if a slug is provided.
            $dataTypeContent = $this->resolveRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType);
        } else {
            // If Model doesn't exist, get data from table name
            $dataTypeContent = call_user_func([DB::table($dataType->name), $getter]);
            $model = false;
        }

        // Check if BREAD is Translatable
        $isModelTranslatable = is_bread_translatable($model);

        // Eagerload Relations
        $this->eagerLoadRelations($dataTypeContent, $dataType, 'browse', $isModelTranslatable);

        // Check if server side pagination is enabled
        $isServerSide = isset($dataType->server_side) && $dataType->server_side;

        // Check if a default search key is set
        $defaultSearchKey = $dataType->default_search_key ?? null;

        // Actions
        $actions = [];
        if (!empty($dataTypeContent->first())) {
            foreach (Voyager::actions() as $action) {
                $action = new $action($dataType, $dataTypeContent->first());

                if ($action->shouldActionDisplayOnDataType()) {
                    $actions[] = $action;
                }
            }
        }

        // Define showCheckboxColumn
        $showCheckboxColumn = false;
        if (Auth::user()->can('delete', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $showCheckboxColumn = true;
        } else {
            foreach ($actions as $action) {
                if (method_exists($action, 'massAction')) {
                    $showCheckboxColumn = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Define orderColumn
        $orderColumn = [];
        if ($orderBy) {
            $index = $dataType->browseRows->where('field', $orderBy)->keys()->first() + ($showCheckboxColumn ? 1 : 0);
            $orderColumn = [[$index, $sortOrder ?? 'desc']];
        }

        $view = 'voyager::bread.browse';

        if (view()->exists("voyager::$slug.browse")) {
            $view = "voyager::$slug.browse";
        }

        // $order = SubOrder::class;

        // $items = $order->items;

        $tokoId = Toko::select('id')->firstWhere('user_id', auth()->id())->id;

        // $orders = SubOrder::where('toko_id', $tokoId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $orders = SubOrder::with('items')->where('toko_id', $tokoId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('sellers.order.index', compact(
            // 'items',
            'orders',
            'actions',
            'dataType',
            'dataTypeContent',
            'isModelTranslatable',
            'search',
            'orderBy',
            'orderColumn',
            'sortOrder',
            'searchNames',
            'isServerSide',
            'defaultSearchKey',
            'usesSoftDeletes',
            'showSoftDeleted',
            'showCheckboxColumn'
        ));
    }

    // public function show(SubOrder $order)
    // {
    //     $items = $order->items;

    //     return view('sellers.order.show', compact('items'));
    // }

    public function markTolak(SubOrder $suborder)
    {
        $suborder->status = 'gagal';
        $suborder->save();

        Alert::info('Order di Proses!', 'Order ditandai proses!');

        return redirect('/seller/orders')->withMessage('Order ditandai proses');
    }

    public function markProses(SubOrder $suborder)
    {
        $suborder->status = 'proses';
        $suborder->save();

        Alert::info('Order di Proses!', 'Order ditandai proses!');

        return redirect('/seller/orders')->withMessage('Order ditandai proses');
    }

    public function markDelivered(SubOrder $suborder)
    {
        $suborder->status = 'selesai';
        $suborder->save();

        // Check all sub order complete
        $pendingSubOrders = $suborder->order->subOrders()->where('status','!=', 'selesai')->count();

        if($pendingSubOrders == 0) {
            $suborder->order()->update(['status'=>'selesai']);
        }

        Alert::success('Order Selesai!', 'Order ditandai selesai!');

        return redirect('/seller/orders')->withMessage('Order ditandai selesai');
    }
}
```

it shows that the error is from the line 42 where it checks the permission and couldn't find the "model_name". please help

 Or maybe if there's another way to use the template?

Comment: Instead of `first()` use `firstOrFail()` to make sure the `Voyager` model exists. `$dataType = Voyager::: ... ->firstOrFail()`.

Comment: it gives the 404 not found error

Comment: That is good. There's the source of your error. `$dataType` returned `null` before, so it threw errors when you assumed it was an instance of `Voyager` in the lines below. Maybe the `getSlug()` method is not returning the correct slug, have you checked that? `dd($slug);` right before `$dataType = ...`.

Comment: My friend, you have a really complicated code, it is huge for being a controller, you have to research about reducing lines and better patterns, as you are not programming badly, but it could be better, it is too huge. You need to use Services or similar to simplify it.

Comment: @IGP I'm pretty sure it's returning the correct slug, since I also have this code for my other controller which works fine

Comment: @matiaslauriti my friend it's a code that comes from the voyager, not mine. what I did is I copied most of the code since I want to use their template otherwise it won't work and add some code to works for my output in the view.blade

Comment: But if it gives you 404, it means `Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();`  throws a ModelNotFoundException. That means the query gives an empty result set.

Comment: @IGP frankly I'm a bit confused tho. this code works perfectly fine when I'm running in my pc, but when I make it onine it just straight up showing that error message

Comment: And are you absolutely sure the record you're trying to get from Voyager exists in the database when you do it online? Try looking for it.